# mysql query to select all data from one table by check the other two atributes in onother table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two (2) tables in one database, I want to display all members that are not paid for either payment:

I tried this but not working:

```
SELECT members.*, payments.amount='', paid_for='fee';
```

Table 1 "**members**" with ID, ROLL NO and NAMES

Table 2 "**payments**" with ID ROLL NO, AMOUNT, PAID_FOR, DATE, STATUS, RECEIPT NO

I want to select all where AMOUNT is empty , PAID FOR  fee

That means if there no payment made, it display all members in database as not paid.

Comment: May want to look at using a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). What have you tried?

Comment: i try this, but not working SELECT members.*, payments.amount='', paid_for='fee';

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT m.ID,m.ROLL_NO,m.NAMES,p.AMOUNT,p.PAID_FOR,p.DATE,p.STATUS,p.RECEIPT_NO

       FROM MEMBERS m  INNER JOIN PAYMENTS p

                 ON m.ROLL_NO = p.ROLL_NO

       WHERE (m.AMOUNT IS NULL OR m.AMOUNT='') AND p.PAID_FOR='fee'

       GROUP BY m.NAMES;
```

Comment: Thanks @dmitryro's but im confused with this "FROM MEMBERS m INNER JOIN PAYMENTS p" what does mean?

Comment: This means that you're querying data from two tables and what is needed is the intersection of the two (data that is present in both tables and has relationship through ROLL_NO. That's the SQL syntax when you use JOIN  of the two tables. Whenever you read (or verify data based on two or more tables you use inner join for intersecting data and outer join for data that is present in one table only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all members with *no payment made*, you may need use `inner join`, and with your requirement, your condition should be `and`, try following;)

```
select distinct t1.*
from members t1
inner join payments t2
on t1.roll_no = t1.roll_no
and t2.paid_for = 'fee' and (t2.amount is null or t2.amount = '')
```

Or could use `exists` like:

```
select t1.*
from members t1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from payments t2 
    where t1.roll_no = t2.roll_no
    and t2.paid_for = 'fee'
    and (t2.amount is null or t2.amount = '')
)
```